# Apache James server UTF-8 support

Tags: postfix-mta, james, apache-james

I'm running Postfix MTA with content filter based on Apache James, whenever Postfix relays a mail to the content-filter, for example with UTF-8 `From` field, it fails to deliver the mail to Apache James with error:

> Sep 08 16:58:37 redacted postfix/smtp[214]: REDACTED:
> to=, relay=content-filter.redacted.net[REDACTED]:10025,
> delay=21, delays=0.71/0.02/20/0, dsn=5.6.7, status=bounced (SMTPUTF8
> is required, but was not offered by host
> content-filter.redacted.net[REDACTED])

I know that Postfix does support UTF-8 by default and in fact is able to receive the message. I can't find any documentation regarding UTF-8 support on Apache James side, or how to configure it.

AFAIK Postfix can't automatically translate UTF-8 to punycode, so I'm really puzzled how can I make it work.